# Array getting converted to ArrayBuffer and giving different behaviour for Blob creation

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, socket.io, arraybuffer

[image]

This is the **result** object returned for saving an **image file** in mongodb using **mongoose**

*Case 1*

The `result.img.data` object has a String attribute **type** and an **Array** attribute **data** and that is exactly what I get on the client side if I `io.emit(event, result)` using **socket.io**

*Case 2*

But if I `io.emit(event, result.img)` then on the client side the object `img.data` becomes an **ArrayBuffer**

**Why is this happening?**

In *Case 1* if I create a **Blob** using `new Blob(new Uint8Array(result.img.data.data))` I get a different **Blob** object and the image file is **unviewable**

But in *Case 2* if I create a **Blob** using `new Blob([img.data])` then a different **Blob** object is created and the file is **viewable**

**Why is this behaviour happening?**

**How can I create a viewable image Blob with the Array instead of the ArrayBuffer?**